# Difficulty with reactive conditional renderImage in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm striking out at my attempts to conditionally display images in the following Shiny app.

There are 2 problems.

The first is that while I can display a picture if I uncomment the `#img(src = "dollar.png")` I can't get the images to display otherwise (though the Alt text associated with the images does display).

The 2nd problem is that my attempts to make the `if` statements work reactively based on the value of `ne` have not been successful.

For `ui.R` I have:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  #  Application title
  titlePanel("My App that Won't Show Pics!"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Simple integer interval
      sliderInput("ns", "Hypothetical NS with Treatment:", 
                  min=100, max=10000, value=4000),

      sliderInput("RPS", "RPS:", 
                  min = 0, max = 50000, value = 21594, step = 100),
      # Revenue Delta
      sliderInput("revDelta", "RPS Delta:", 
                  min = -10000, max = 5000, value = -4900, step = 100),
      # NS Lift
      sliderInput("nsLift", "NS Lift (See PPT for example results):", 
                  min = 0, max = .4, value = .18, step = .001)

    ),

    # Show a table summarizing the values entered
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("values"),
      imageOutput("image1")
      #img(src = "dollar.png")

    )
  )
))
```

For `server.R` I have:

```
library(shiny)
net_effect <- function(ns, revDelta, nsLift, RPS) {
  trBase     <- (ns/(1 + nsLift)) * RPS
  trOffer    <- (ns * RPS) + (ns * revDelta)
  netEffect  <- round(trOffer - trBase)
  return(paste("$",format(netEffect, big.mark=","),sep=""))
}

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  sliderValues <- reactive({

    # Compose data frame
    data.frame(
      Name = c("New Students with Offer", 
               "Rev per Student", "Net Effect"),
      Value = as.character(c(input$ns, 
                             input$RPS,
                             ne <- net_effect(input$ns, input$revDelta, input$nsLift, input$RPS))), 
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  }) 

  # Show the values using an HTML table
  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })
  # image2 sends pre-rendered images
  output$image1 <- renderImage({

    if (net_effect(input$ns, input$revDelta, input$nsLift, input$RPS) < 0) {
      return(list(
        src = "images/red_dollar.png",
        contentType = "image/png",
        alt = "We're losing money!"
      ))
    } else if (net_effect(input$ns, input$revDelta, input$nsLift, input$RPS) > 0) {
      return(list(
        src = "images/dollar.png",
        filetype = "image/png",
        alt = "We're making money!"
      ))
    }

  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that pictures `dollar.png` and `dolar_red.png` are in the folder `www` which is in the same directory as the server.R and ui.r.

> The 2nd problem is that my attempts to make the if statements work
>   reactively based on the value of ne have not been successful.

This is because you are comparing a character string to 0 which doesn't make sence. I've made some changes in the server code that should solve the first problem as well.

EDIT: I forgot to add changed `net_effect`function

```
net_effect <- function(ns, revDelta, nsLift, RPS) {
  trBase     <- (ns/(1 + nsLift)) * RPS
  trOffer    <- (ns * RPS) + (ns * revDelta)
  return(round(trOffer - trBase)) # new return value 
}

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  net <- reactive({ 
    net_effect(input$ns, input$revDelta, input$nsLift, input$RPS)
  })


  sliderValues <- reactive({

    # Compose data frame
    data.frame(
      Name = c("New Students with Offer", 
               "Rev per Student", "Net Effect"),
      Value = as.character(c(input$ns, 
                             input$RPS,
                             ne <- paste("$",format( net(), big.mark=","),sep="") )), 
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  }) 


  # Show the values using an HTML table
  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })

  output$image1 <- renderImage({

    if ( net() < 0) { 
      return(list(
        src = "www/red_dollar.png",
        contentType = "image/png",
        alt = "We're losing money!"
      ))
    } else if (net() > 0) {
      return(list(
        src = "www/dollar.png",
        filetype = "image/png",
        alt = "We're making money!"
      ))
    }

  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
})
```

Comment: Update: Actually now that I try it seems the text and images still aren't displaying/updating. They are in www and they display if I just use `img` in `ui.R` as a test...

Comment: OK, I got it. I had to add `www` to the `src` path